# (custom keyboard) I want to make a key labeled "ADV" but it should send the content like SEND button

Tags: android

xml file,

```
<Key android:codes="900" android:keyLabel="ADV" />
```

the code for 900 is (java file, switch),

```
case 900:
    CharSequence text = "adventure";
    ic.commitText(text, 1);
    break;
```

let me know the changes to be done to send the word on keypress.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? ([mcve])

Comment: just add the case code for SEND/DONE button in addition to that case 900. no errors but not taking that command. (ic.sendKeyEvent.....)

Comment: ic.commitText(text, 1) && ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IME_ACTION_SEND` is the ime option set by EditText which enables your enter as send.
To send on such a field :

```
ic.commitText(text, 1);
KeyEvent kd = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER); 
KeyEvent ku = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
ic.sendKeyEvent(kd);
ic.sendKeyEvent(ku);
```

Comment: KeyEvent kd = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER); KeyEvent ku = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER); ic.sendKeyEvent(kd); ic.sendKeyEvent(ku);

This might work